# Consulta a tabla muchos a muchos

Tags: mysql, sql

Estimada comunidad, hace muchas horas que me llevo dando vuelta con este código y no he podido encontrar la solución, espero puedan ayudarme.

Mi base de datos es la siguiente 
[image: ,]

[image: tabla categoria_productos]

Para entender un poco el sistema, básicamente los productos son automóviles,  por ende pueden tener mas de una categoría, que pueden ser: rapido, todo terreno, 0 kilometros, etc..

Mi problema surge en realizar la consulta para buscar estos autos, el cliente, puede elegir las categorías a consultar, por ejemplo: todo terreno, espacioso, rápido, etc.. y en base a esas categorías que el cliente selecciona debe mostrar los productos que cuenten con 1 o mas de ellas.

He probado con inner join pero si tengo el usuario selecciona 2 categorías que tiene un producto, me devuelve el producto repetido.

por ejemplo:

```
 SELECT * FROM productos 
 INNER JOIN categoria_productos 
 ON categoria_productos.id_producto = categoria_productos.id_producto 
 WHERE categoria_productos.id_categoria = '4' 
 OR categoria_productos.id_categoria = '9'
```

Ahí estoy buscando un producto con la categoría 4 y 9, efectivamente el producto id 1 tiene esas 2 categorías, pero me repite 2 veces el mismo producto.

Comment: En el resultado de la consulta necesitas tener los campos de la relación?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La consulta es incorrecta por `ON categoria_productos.id_producto = categoria_productos.id_producto`. (mismos campos de la misma tabla ????)

Además puedes consultar los productos que "estén en" ([`IN`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx)) y a agregando dentro la consulta las categorias seleccionadas.

```
 SELECT * FROM productos 
 WHERE productos.id IN 
 (SELECT categoria_productos.id_producto FROM categoria_productos 
 WHERE categoria_productos.id_categoria = '4' OR categoria_productos.id_categoria = '9')
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal como indicaba Roy, la consulta es incorrecta (por la relación en el `inner Join`), la solución que él da con el `IN` solo es eficaz con pocos registros. Si solo quieres campos de la tabla de productos puedes hacer un `distinct`.

```
SELECT distinct productos.id_producto, marca, modelo, ...
FROM productos 
INNER JOIN categoria_productos 
ON productos.id_producto = categoria_productos.id_producto 
WHERE categoria_productos.id_categoria = '4' 
OR categoria_productos.id_categoria = '9'
```

Comment: Este código también entrega 2 veces el mismo producto repetido.

Answer (score 1):

Hay una tercera opción, para mi gusto más rápida y eficaz de cara al rendimiento del motor SQL, y es usar el comando **EXISTS**.

Usar **IN** es como usar al final un **OR**, y usar **DISTINCT** provoca dos operaciones: seleccionar todo y filtrar los resultados. El comando **EXISTS** actúa como un tipo de filtro **AND** y evita cruces **INNER** si no vas a utilizarlos para sacar sus campos en **SELECT**.

Sería algo de este estilo:

```
SELECT prod.id_producto, prod.id_categoria
FROM productos prod
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM categoria_productos cat WHERE prod.id_producto=cat.id_producto
and (cat.id_categoria = '4' OR cat.id_categoria = '9'))
```

Un consejo en último lugar: en la medida de los posible, siempre intenta escribir los campos a utilizar en el SELECT, evitando * o [alias_tabla].* 
No pasa nada, pero de cara a tener un código limpio siempre se recomienda esa buena práctica.

Comment: Al ejecutar la consulta da error, ya que la en la tabla producto no se encuentra la columna "id_categoria", para ello existe una relación muchos a muchos en la tabla categoria_productos. La solución mas acertada es la de Roy, buscare una forma de mejorar el rendimiento en base a su consulta.

Comment: Tienes razón, Maikel. En mi respuesta puse mal la relación del WHERE dentro del EXISTS. Solo por confirmar, y para tu testing, prueba lo que edito en la respuesta, a ver si te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza un LeftJoin y utiliza el comando **in** para poner varias **variables** de una sola columna.

```
SELECT * FROM productos 
 LEFT JOIN categoria_productos 
 ON productos.id_producto = categoria_productos.id_producto 
 WHERE categoria_productos.id_categoria in ('4','9')
```

Comment: Se repite 2 veces el mismo producto, ya que tiene las 2 categorías.